# Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefult is not a function ( Also i am trying to updating my .js file to try solve the problem but not working)

Tags: javascript, php, html, error-handling, localhost

I am trying to build a messaging app in php and javascript languages
But I have a problem, which is that when I linked the index file with the signup.js file
And when I opened the file in a local host, I was exposed to this problem: **Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefult is not a function**

(I tried to modify the function in the java file, but the browser does not accept the modification, no matter how much I update the file, I do not know why and how I can solve the problem)

[ScreenShot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O4eB.png)

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
const form = document.querySelector(".signup form"),
continueBtn = form.querySelector(".button input");

form.onsubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault(); //formun gönderilmesini engelleme 
}
continueBtn.onclick = () =>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating XML object 
    xhr.open("POST" , "php/signup.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(xhr.status === 200){
                let data = xhr.response;
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
        
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viweport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>OnlineMesajlaşmaUygulaması</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section class="form signup">  
                    <header>Mesajlaşma Uygulaması</header>
                    <form action="#">
                    <div class="error-txt">This is an error message!</div>
                    <div class="name-details">
                        <div class="field input">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field input">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field input">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field input">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter new password ">
                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field image">
                        <label>Select Image</label>
                        <input type="file">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field button">
                        <input type="submit" value="Continue to Chat">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="link">Alredy Signed up?<a href="#">Login now</a> </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    <script src="javascript/pass-show-hide.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/signup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code in the question is different from the code in the screenshot.